# In Spring Rest annotation based CRUD application , but getting the following exception

Tags: spring, rest

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fI0J.png)Please help me how to resolve the following exception.
enter image description here

Following is my hibernate cinfiguration file,

```
package com.springrest.annotationbased.crudexampleapplication.configuration;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.springrest.annotationbased.crudexampleapplication.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:applicaton.properties" )
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String []{ "com.springrest.annotationbased.crudexampleapplication.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;

    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource ();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource();
    }

    public Properties hibernateProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hiberante.hbm2dll.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired //SessionFactory obj need to be injected as dependent in HibernateTransactionManager to provide support for the transaction for the sessions created by SessionFactory 
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.springrest.annotationbased.crudexampleapplication.configuration.HibernateConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicaton.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:673)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:519)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4851)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicaton.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:72)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:58)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:231)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: How can we help without you providing the full codebase? A GitHub link would help.

Comment: As it clearly states, place the file application.properties in classpath.

Comment: following is the screen shot of application structure and already I added the same in classpath.                                                                                                     
          https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fI0J.png

Answer (score 0):

Change the value from `classpath:applicaton.properties` to `classpath:application.properties`
in HibernateConfiguration in line (application instead of applicaton):

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:applicaton.properties" )
```

Looks like a typo.